# Accessing ICloud Drive files from an iPad

Tags: ipad, icloud, imac

I've added some files (photographs) to iCloud drive on my iMac. 
Now, I'd like to access the files on my iPad.
I've enabled the setting in "iCloud" on the iPad, like all of the tutorials say.

Now- how can I find those files using my iPad?

Answer (score 0):

- You must check you are logged with the *same iCloud account* both on your Mac and on your iPad, if not, log in to the same one.
- Open the *Files* app on your iPad and click on "*iCloud Drive*" under Locations.
- The files you have uploaded from your Mac should be there. If you are not seeing them, you might want to click on the symbol with the 4 squares (next the the "Select" button) and click on "Date" until the symbol next to "Date" turns to a v-like shape, meaning that it will sort the files by date added starting from most recent. Also, it depends on the options you have selected but the files may also be in the Downloads folder in iCloud.